# Dust vortex under helicopter

Tags: animation, particles, physics, animation-nodes, loop

I have a helicopter model and I have it flying above a desert.  It is stationary but with the blades moving over a desert with an ocean mod.

How do I create a realistic dust and wind vortex on the sand under the helicopter?  I'm open to any method as long as the end result looks realistic.  The best solution for this project is an animation that loops.

Comment: It sounds like you're animating.  A smoke sim is probably the most realistic option, but a large volume with a lot of detail means render times may become a concern.  How open are you to approaches that fake it?

Comment: I am open to anything that works.

Comment: I have no answer, but you may want to monitor https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/smoke-simulation-realistic-dirt-dust-trail-in-blender-2-9 that is a similar question