# MANTAFOLW - Realistic Dirt/Dust trail

Tags: interface, smoke-simulation, collision, versions, resolution

I'm following the ["Making Realistic Dust trail"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139754/making-a-realistic-dust-trail) question which is not accurate for today blender smoke sim interface.

I try to reproduce this answer for cgslav but in blender 2.9 which does not have the same interface for smoke sim.
After discussing the most accurate question would be:
**How to replicate the 2.82 worflow described later on the pasge to Mantaflow?**

Is that possible? I tried on my side and did not succeed at all. I would love to understand how to translate this method.

Original answer from @CGSLAV

[image]

1. Create emitter with Real World Scale - this is important, as **Smoke** sim can differ based on scale.
   Mine has ~56x7m.
   Apply Scale!
2. Add to it Quick Smoke - F3 > Quick Smoke.
3. Scale Domain in Edit Mode to make it as big as you need.
4. In Domain settings I've changed only Resolution - 192, Temp. Diff. - -0.04, Adaptive Domain - checked and High Resolution - checked + Resolution Division > 2.

[image]

5.Collision Object.
This is most important thing to do here. Set it as Smoke > Collision and Animated.

[image]

6. Now you have 3 options how to interact with smoke.

- Allow object to "sink" into smoke.
- Attach to object "plow" to raise smoke and not be visible in Render.
- Attach Force Field to object to "suck" smoke from the ground.

Comment: Not an answer: Since v 2.82 smoke simulation are created with a different technology called "mantaflow" and is indeed a completely different interface than the old one.

Comment: Not an answer: Ok, thank you for the information susu, so the question would be more how to translate the 2.82 sim workflow to mantalflow tech inside blender? I tried a lot and did not get amazing results to be honest.

Comment: I don't have an answer but you may also want to monitor a similar question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209040/dust-vortex-under-helicopter